# Zebra SDK cant write tag

Tags: android, rfid, zebra-printers

Device:TC20

I am getting an exception com.zebra.rfid.api3.OperationFailureException on last line

```
override fun writeTagID(tagId: String, newId: HexString, password: HexString) {

    // конфигурация взята из офф. документации https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-15/guide/tagwrite/

    reader.Config.setAccessOperationWaitTimeout(3000)

    reader.Actions.Inventory.stop()
    reader.Config.dpoState = DYNAMIC_POWER_OPTIMIZATION.DISABLE

    val tagData: TagData? = null
    val tagAccess = TagAccess()
    val writeAccessParams = tagAccess.WriteAccessParams()
    val writeData: String = newId.value

    writeAccessParams.accessPassword = password.value.toLong(16)
    writeAccessParams.memoryBank = MEMORY_BANK_EPC
    writeAccessParams.offset = 2 // offset is two for EPC ID

    writeAccessParams.setWriteData(writeData)
    // set retries in case of partial write happens
    writeAccessParams.writeRetries = 3
    // data length in words
    writeAccessParams.writeDataLength = writeData.length / 4
    // 5th parameter bPrefilter flag is true which means API will apply pre filter internally
    // 6th parameter should be true in case of changing EPC ID it self i.e. source and target both is EPC
    reader.Actions.TagAccess.writeWait(tagId, writeAccessParams, null, tagData, true, true)
}
```

I read the documentation. Tried increasing the timeout but still getting an exception.
[image: Вот логи ошибки]

```
2021-07-30 14:26:09.978 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err: com.zebra.rfid.api3.OperationFailureException
2021-07-30 14:26:09.979 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at com.zebra.rfid.api3.j1.a(SourceFile:4)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.979 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at com.zebra.rfid.api3.TagAccess.writeWait(SourceFile:34)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.980 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at ru.app.rfid_android.core.reader.zebra.ZebraReaderAndroid.writeTagID-e7Vaky0(ZebraReaderAndroid.kt:218)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.980 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at ru.app.rfid_android.core.model.ReaderRec.writeAndReadTag-ToYnHGU(ReaderRec.kt:269)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.980 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at ru.app.rfid_android.core.model.ReaderRec$writeBank$1.invoke(ReaderRec.kt:246)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.981 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at ru.app.rfid_android.core.model.ReaderRec$writeBank$1.invoke(ReaderRec.kt:30)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.982 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at ru.app.rfid_android.core.model.ReaderRec$runCatchingAndTimeout$1.invoke(ReaderRec.kt:371)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.982 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at ru.app.rfid_android.core.model.ReaderRec$runCatchingAndTimeout$1.invoke(ReaderRec.kt:30)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.983 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at ru.app.rfid_android.core.UtilsKt$runWithTimeout$stuffToDo$1.run(Utils.kt:82)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.983 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.984 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.984 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.984 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2021-07-30 14:26:09.984 13780-13998/ru.app.rfid_android W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It might help if edit your question to include the full stacktrace output instead of the graphic you posted. Also, can you include the version where you set the timeout so we can check the arguments are correct, etc.

Comment: @dstricks Hello! Thanks for your feedback. When I changed the timeout I just changed the value of reader.Config.setAccessOperationWaitTimeout (3000). I also set the full stacktrace when an error occurs, I will be glad to help

Comment: What happens if you increase the timeout from 3 seconds to 15 seconds? Does it still timeout? I'm not familiar with RFID so I don't know what a reasonable timeout would be... but just trying to rule out that it's not a valid timeout because the write actually does take longer than 3 second (which is what you set).

Comment: @dstricks No. The default timeout is 1 second. I set it to 3 seconds and even 12 seconds, which is a lot. That's the problem with the SDK it seems to me.